# Why does the solution step size not change significantly after the maximum step size is specified?

Tags: differential-equations

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]
Needs["FunctionApproximations`"]

system = GetNDSolveProblem[
  "Robertson"](*A built-in system of equations describing chemically \
related systems*)
sol1 = NDSolve[system, Method -> "Adams"];
StepDataPlot[sol1]
sol2 = NDSolve[system, 
   Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}];
StepDataPlot[sol2]
```

The `StepDataPlot` function can draw the step size information in the numerical solution process.
We can see that the step size information to these two methods of solving differential equations are very different.

[image]

However, when I specified the maximum step size in the following code, the step size taken by the solution basically did not change significantly (especially the first step did not reach the specified value):

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"]
Needs["FunctionApproximations`"]
system = GetNDSolveProblem[
  "Robertson"](*A built-in system of equations describing chemically \
related systems*)
sol1 = NDSolve[system, StartingStepSize -> 0.01, MaxStepSize -> 0.01, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
Plot[Evaluate[Subscript[Y, 2][T] /. sol1], {T, 0, 0.3}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
StepDataPlot[sol1]


sol2 = NDSolve[system, StartingStepSize -> 0.5, MaxStepSize -> 0.5, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
StepDataPlot[sol2]
```

[image]

I want to know why the step size of the first step does not use the value specified by the `StartingStepSize` parameter? And why can't the `MaxStepSize` parameter affect the step size effectively? It is best to explain these reasons with smaller, simple examples.

Comment: Just in case: do you know what's plotted by `StepDataPlot`?

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I probably understand that the `StepDataPlot` function can plot the step size used in each step when solving the differential system.

Comment: In my experience with solvers, the maximum step size sets an upper bound on the step, but not a minimum bound. Same sometimes with an initial step size. Other accuracy goals can overrule. From the documentation, "NDSolve adapts its step size so that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal." Relaxing these may allow your step size to increase.